# How to change the author of the last github commit?

Tags: git, github

Possible duplicate, but I hit the following issue when using those answers.

**Situation**:

I didn't set up my github locally when I pushed a commit so the author information is incorrect. I've now set the global user.name and email correctly. But I would like to update that commit with the new information.

**Attempt**:
Starting from the origin

```
git checkout my_branch 

git pull 

git commit --amend --author="My Name <me@example.com>" --no-edit

git push
```

triggers the following error:

```
 ! [rejected]            mybranch -> mybranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xyz'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What is the correct way to pass the update to the live repo?

Comment: You need to *force* push to replace the existing history, but be careful about doing this on repos other people are also trying to work on.

Comment: do only force push if no one else is working on the same branch! otherwise you might overwrite changes of other users

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have already pushed previous commit into your remote git repository(github). If so, then you can use push force command to rewrite the previous commit author.

```
git push --force
```